Failure from isort because it's been told to skip a file
Running isort as a plug-in under poetry, poe and pytest, a task fails because it detects an in-file command to skip the file, which I would have thought would instruct isort to, you know, skip the damn file :-)
In our pyproject.toml file, we have the task and section as follows:
isort-junit = "pytest projname --isort --junitxml=${OUT_DIR}/xml/isort.xml"

[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
line_length = 180
force_single_line = true
single_line_exclusions = ["typing"]

The file in question starts as follows (those first three lines are added by our build process after the file has been generated, this should prevent tools like mypt, pylint, etc, from complaining about code we have no control over:
# fmt: off
# pylint: skip-file
"""isort:skip_file"""
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# sources: projname_messages.proto
# plugin: python-betterproto

It appears to be recognising the fact that the file should be skipped but the isort-junit task is failing because of that:
2024-05-15T04:45:24 <<< INFO [1bfcdaf9]:
    projname/messaging/projname_messages.py::ISORT FAILED [18%]

(and, later in the output)

2024-05-15T04:45:26 <<< INFO [1bfcdaf9]: 
    FAILED projname/messaging/projname_messages.py::ISORT -
    isort.exceptions.FileSkipComment:
    /opt/pysetup/projname/messaging/projname_messages.py
    contains a file skip comment and was skipped.

It's very nice of isort to let me know that it should skip the file. It would be nicer if it went the extra distance and skipped it without causing an error.
Does anyone have any idea why it's doing this, and how to fix it?

Version info follows if needed:



Component
Version




isort
5.13.2


poethepoet
0.13.1


poetry
1.5.1.1


pytest
7.4.4


pytest-isort
4.0.0


python
3.8



